# Daphne server halts after executing a very long process in a Django Channels-based architecture

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, django-channels

I am building a system for processing data and then train ML models using sklearn's builtins. I used digital ocean for deployment with Ubuntu, Nginx, Gunicorn, Daphne, Django, and Channels.

All features work fine until it is required to train larger datasets through channels (sockets) asgi connection. When the execution starts, it takes few moments until the server (asgi) stops responding and all other WebSockets stop working, HTTP ones are fine though.

I have followed the following tutorial for deployment: [CodingWithMitch Channels Deployment](https://github.com/mitchtabian/HOWTO-django-channels-daphne), when I restart the server again with these commands, everything starts working fine except the training part (the long process):

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo systemctl restart redis.service
service daphne restart
```

Restarting Daphne was the critical one I noticed. The confusing part is, the server logs show no error whatsoever. It seems to be an issue with the websockets keepalive timeout as my initial guess, but even after I increase the timeout in my nginx.conf file it and restart, it doesn't change the behavior:

> /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
server {
    server_name 159.203.13.90;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/django/EasyAI;
    }
    
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_read_timeout 10d;
        proxy_send_timeout 10d;
    }
 
    location /ws/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_read_timeout 10d;
        proxy_send_timeout 10d;
    }
```

}

Are there any suggestions of what could be causing this problem?

Comment: Is it possible that you somewhere have a blocking sync call in your otherwise async app?  Maybe that only has an effect if the blocking function takes longer with a huge dataset. So you never get an error message. It would be interesting to find out (print(...)) where the blocking socket actually is when the other sockets stop. I understood you know which socket is the one that causes the "freeze".

Comment: I actually have traced back with print, and it seems it is getting stuck at the pipeline.fit functions, and if you know sklearn, you know it either works or fails from start. My guess would be related sockets timeout but unfortunately cannot debug it or fix it even though I have increased their values in my nginx.conf file.

Comment: I am not familiar with sklearn - so the only question for me is: is pipeline.fit awaited or a "normal" sync function? If it is not awaited it will block all other sockets. If it is sync the better way would be to run a longer process as a worker in the background. I cant help more here I think.